# How to implement HTML5 audio chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What are good resources to create dedicated channel audio chat application using html5 web sockets? Is it possible? Actually I'm imaginning to develop a voice chat application using html5 web sockets. Can anyone help me out in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is the way you can start with , I 'm currently work on a project that I must use voice chat HTML5 implemented !!
if you got any details ,provide me with :) http://marakana.com/bookshelf/html5_tutorial/web_sockets.html
*-- Mustafa Adel ELnagar Microsoft HTML5 champion*

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that developing a voice chat application with pure html5 is possible at the moment, as most browsers don't support audio recording yet. You'll be able to use `navigator.getusermedia` ([W3C Draft](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#idl-def-MediaStreamOptions)) for that purpose in the future, but AFAIK, this method is not supported by any mainstream browser yet. So I guess, you'll have to fall back to proprietary technology like flash to develop a web based audio chat system that presently works for most users.

Comment: It's now 2015 and I believe it is more than possible using WebRTC. I thing Google Hangouts is a great example of this!